# How to prevent double-encoding characters when posting to activity stream?

Tags: json, ibm-connections

In IBM Connections (versions 4.0 and 4.5), I'm posting JSON like that shown at the bottom of the question to activity streams.
The "title" field in the data uses a custom title template, defined in the "com.ibm.lconn.news.nls.templatePlaceholders.properties" file as:

```
GENERAL.kudos.boards.entry.created={actor} created the {activityEntry} entry in the {Target} board.
```

The title template is processed, but various characters (such as ampersands and quotes) get double-encoded before the title appears in the Connections UI.

For example, the JSON shown below produces an activity-stream entry that looks like this in the Connections UI:

```
Scott Leis created the Entry 9 &amp; test entry in the Scott's Test Activity board.
```

And if I make a GET request to check the JSON on the server, part of the entry title containing the ampersand looks like this, with the ampersand double-encoded:

```
Entry 9 &amp;amp; test
```

How do I prevent such characters from being double-encoded?

The original JSON is below.
I have also tried encoding the ampersand as `&amp;` in the JSON before posting, but that causes it to be triple-encoded in the UI.

```
{
    "target":{
        "objectType":"task-list",
        "id":"35bf524b-1651-48d4-afea-e8a428f8f1ff",
        "displayName":"Scott's Test Activity",
        "url":"https://server.company.net.au/kudosboards/#board/35bf524b-1651-48d4-afea-e8a428f8f1ff"
    },
    "generator":{
        "id":"kudos"
    },
    "actor":{
        "id":"@me"
    },
    "connections":{
        "broadcast":"false",
        "isPublic":"true",
        "rollupid":"urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:activities.unknown:5b824624-01be-49bc-9485-d75f09ba0098",
        "saved":"false",
    },
    "title":"${kudos.boards.entry.created}",
    "updated":"2014-04-23T03:50:00.000Z",
    "object":{
        "summary":"",
        "objectType":"entry",
        "id":"5b824624-01be-49bc-9485-d75f09ba0098",
        "displayName":"Entry 9 & test",
        "url":"https://server.company.net.au/kudosboards/#board/35bf524b-1651-48d4-afea-e8a428f8f1ff"
    },
    "verb":"post"
}
```

Comment: have you tried encoding the & before posting?

Comment: @PaulBastide - Yes I have. That causes triple-encoding in the UI. I've also added this detail as an edit to the question.

Comment: is the file on a Linux  machine and did you edit it with Windows? maybe dos2unix or unix2dos would show extra characters?  I'll ping someone to look at it

Comment: @PaulBastide - The Connections server I'm using for testing is Linux. I'm editing my JSON before posting in a 3rd-party Windows text editor, and posting it to Connections using RESTClient in Firefox on Windows. Also, I get the same double-encoded result from activity stream entries created via the SBT Java API running on the Connections server.

Comment: chatted with the Architect, they are going to look at it, and most likely it's a part of processing the update when it's received.

Comment: you'll have to open a PMR to get a Fix for it, but yes it is an issue.